# Datatables.net post whole table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery and am having an issue retrieving posting data between the different pages.

So I have a checkbox in each row on the table. If a user selects a checkbox on page 1 then switches to page 2 and selects a checkbox and then submits, the controller then receives a blank object. If they submit from page 1 I can see the items from the first page. Is there a way to post the whole table?

Second issue, I have two buttons at the bottom that should do two different things. So either I could call to the method and then determine which button was pressed or just call that specific method.  How do I accomplish this?

### Razor Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageSelected", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ManageApplicationForm" }))
{
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Students[i].Student.StudentUserID)
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 1px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Students[i].IsSelected)</td>
                <td>@Model.Students[i].Student.User.FullName() </td>

            </tr>
        }

        </tbody>
    </table>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-action" id="acceptBtn" value="Accept" name="command">Accept</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Decline" name="command">Decline</button>

}
```

### Controller stub

```
 public ActionResult ManageSelected(AdminManageApplicationsViewModel model, string command)
```

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30968685

Comment: Almost exactly like my problem! Thanks!